# How did the DOCTYPE tag come about?

Tags: html, doctype

I was wondering how the DOCTYPE tag came about.

I understand the purpose of the tag which is to alert a browser on how it should render the HTML document, but I don't understand why they created a new tag for it as opposed to putting that information as an attribute of the HTML tag: the HTML tag can already take a language attribute.

I thought it might have to do with preprocessing since the doctype is required at the very beginning of each document (though the HTML tag would be at the beginning of the document if the DOCTYPE wasn't there), but I was hoping for a more definitive answer than my own conjecture.

I've tried using several queries in Google for the answer, but most return the "why you should use a doctype" instead.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: @Matt Interesting article. But it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I was wondering about the logic of using the doctype tag as opposed to sticking that information in... maybe an attribute of the HTML tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand the purpose of the tag which is to alert a browser on how it should render the HTML document

No.

The Doctype associates an SGML document with a DTD. The DTD is used for validation (is describes which elements and attributes are allowed where), and to expand entity references. HTML 4.x and lower are SGML applications.

XML is derived from SGML and the Doctype is used for the same purpose in XML. XHTML is an XML application.

The use to determine rendering modes was a hack by browser vendors trying to deal with web pages designed around bugs in browsers.

HTML 5 reinvents the Doctype purpose for backwards compatibility with the render mode switch.

> I don't understand why they created a new tag for it as opposed to putting that information as an attribute of the HTML tag

Then a validator would have have to parse the HTML start tag before knowing if an HTML start tag was allowed there, and it would have to parse it before being able to expand any entity references used in its attribute values.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. This question was bothering me for some time. I never knew that it was a hack; most articles make it sound it came about as a natural thing. Once again, many thanks for your detailed response.